# WAS Liberty on Intellij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, websphere-liberty, was

I'm trying to integrate `Intellij IDEA` with `WebSphere Application Server`. According to this instruction: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/developing-apps-with-intellij-idea-and-liberty-profile/
I should see something like this
[example image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUYTp.png)

But instead I see this:
[example image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lIeu.png)

I do all step in this guide, but i stop on step 10.
Can you help me or give some advice?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to click that folder icon to the right of the text box, and find the folder where you extracted the server zip file in step 1.

Comment: @Jeyu That's great. If this answered your question, please click on the grey checkmark to the left of the answer to mark it as the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: You are talking about WAS Liberty but link you provided is for Open Liberty.  They are 2 different products.  Would you mind sharing how did you get WAS Liberty server into IntelliJ?  Thanks